# How to make a view transparent in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing some UI designing for class on an open source project. I'm trying to make the appbar and tabs of this tablayout transparent but no matter what I do they remain white. If it were transparent the background would be able to be seen but i get this white instead. 
I have tried-

1. changing the xml values in the mainfragments xml to transparent
2. changing the colors.xml values to transparent (all of them because i wanted 
   to be sure)
3. changing and even removing the "light theme" and "dark theme" values in 
   styles.xml and removing the app theme line in the android manifest
   `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen.Light"`
   Am I missing something else that i can try? I would be very thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: post tabs and toolbar xml code.

Comment: You need to customize `style`. There is a lot of same quesions in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

in color.xml
value @color/transparent is the color value #00000000

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

set alpha value in layout XML or dynamically in view to make view transparent.

```
view.setAlpha(40);
```

oR add from xml - value between 0 to 1

```
android:alpha="0.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio **res->values->colors.xml**

[image]

**Step 1** : For selecting color

**Step 2** : Changing transparency(you can move left to right for adjusting transparency )

**Step 3** : Give this color as views background

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/color_name">
```

This may help you.